# How to use cosine similarity within triplet loss

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, loss-functions, triplet-loss

The triplet loss is defined as follows:

$$
L(A, P, N) = \max(\Vert f(A) - f(P) \Vert^2- \Vert f(A) - f(N)\Vert^2 + \textrm{margin}, 0)
$$

where $A$=anchor, $P$=positive, and $N$=negative are the data samples in the loss, and $\rm margin$ is the minimum distance between the anchor and positive/negative samples.

I read somewhere that $(1 - cosine\_similarity)$ may be used instead of the $L_2\ distance$.

Note that I am using `Tensorflow` - and the cosine similarity loss is defined that When it is a negative number between -1 and 0, 0 indicates orthogonality and values closer to -1 indicate greater similarity. The values closer to 1 indicate greater dissimilarity. So, it is the opposite of cosine similarity metric.

Another resource I found is the cosine similarity layer [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss.html), but it is not a triplet loss.

Any suggestions on how to write my triplet loss with cosine similarity?

**Edit**

I am having some luck with this where I see the loss function go down

```
 loss = (1 - an_distance) + tf.maximum(ap_distance + self.margin, 0.0)
```

where `ap_distance` and `an_distance` are the cosine similarity loss (not metric - so the measure is reversed). So I wonder if the terms should be flipped.

**Edit 2**

Its been a while but my best advice is to use the same metric as a distance function in training and inference. For example, if you use L2 inside the triplet/ quadruplet loss - don't use cosine in inference to compare vectors.

I ended up putting the cosine distance in the triplet (actually used quadruplet) - and used the same metric in inference for comparison and worked amazing.

Here is somewhat of the sudo code:

```
    margin = 0.25
    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)
    
    ap_distance = loss_fn(anchor, positive)
    an_distance_one = loss_fn(anchor, negative_one)
    an_distance_two = loss_fn(anchor, negative_two)
    
    ap_distance, an_distance_one, an_distance_two = siamese_network(data)
    loss_one = tf.maximum(ap_distance - an_distance_one + 0.5 * margin, 0.0)
    loss_two = tf.maximum(ap_distance - an_distance_two + margin, 0.0)
    loss = loss_one + loss_two
```

Comment: sqrt[2(1-cos_sim)] is indeed a special case of euclidean distance called chord distance. Due to the law of cosines https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158/3277. 1-cos_sim, the cosine distance, is thus like squared euclidean distance.

Comment: Cosine distance is not the only angular distance. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/565057/22311

Comment: @Sycorax I am using cosine similarity metric to compare vectors after training; hence, I wanted to use the same distance during training. What do you suggest for the triplet loss.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps equation 9 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.03512)<sup>1</sup> is useful. Using your notation:

$$
\begin{equation}
L_{\text{cos}}(A, P, N) = -\log \frac{\exp\{s (f(A)^T f(P) - m)\}}{\exp\{s (f(A)^T f(P) - m)\} + \exp\{s f(A)^T f(N)\}}
\end{equation}
$$

where

- $s > 1$ is a hyperparameter specifying the radius of the hypersphere where features live (the authors argue that increasing this allows for greater angular separation b/t features, and thus greater discrimination)
- $m$ is the margin hyperparameter (in terms of cosine distance)
- and all features were normalized to have unit norm (that's why the dot products above are the same as cosine similarity).

### References

1. Unde, Amit Satish, and Renu M. Rameshan. "MOTS R-CNN: Cosine-margin-triplet loss for multi-object tracking." arXiv preprint arXiv:2102.03512 (2021).